# How many elements to add to make converse of Lagrange's theorem true?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose I have a subset $S$ of some group $G$, let's say that $S$ passes Lagrange's test (*i.e.*: order of $|S|$ is factor of order of $|G|$) but it is not a subgroup of $G$. How many more elements on a minimum should I add to $S$ such that I get a subgroup?

1. One thing I figured out already about this is that if we denote $x$ the number of elements to be added,

$$ (|S|+x)k' = |G|= |S| k$$

Taking everything $ \bmod |S|$, we have:

$$\left[ x (k' \bmod |S| )\right] \bmod |S| = 0$$

If $|S|$ is prime, then I think $k' \bmod |S|=0$ as there are any zero divisors.

2. $|G| \bmod (|S| +x)=0$ by Lagrange's theorem

What more can be said? Are there any special cases worth knowing?

Comment: The smallest possible $x$ is the smallest number such that $|S|+x$ divides $|G|$, isn't it?

Comment: Right @freakish

Comment: And that can be pretty much any number between $2$ and $|G|/2$, meaning if $x\in [2,n/2]$ then there is a group $G$ of order $n$ (I think cyclic will do) and a subset $S$ such that $S$ can be turned into a subgroup by adding $x$ (and not less) elements. So what exactly you are looking for here?

Comment: It can happen that one has to add all elements. Take for example $G=\{e,a,a^2,\ldots a^5\}$ where $a^6=e$ and $S=\{a\}$. Then $S$ passes Lagrange test. Adding more elements still could give $S=\{a,a^2,a^3,a^4\}$, but the identity is still missing. Since we don't know whether or not the identity has been added, we need all elements in general.

Comment: @DietrichBurde well, when $S\subseteq G$ is a set of generators then you have to add all elements regardless of the size of $S$.

Comment: @freakish Yes, but isn't this what I said? So in general we have to add all elements? Perhaps the question should be formulated more clearly.

Comment: Like which part was unclear @DietrichBurde

Comment: This question seems to be about a difference (in terms of number of elements) between $S$ and $\langle S\rangle$ with a twist that $|S|$ divides $|G|$. Which doesn't seem that important.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks: suppose we have a subset $S$ of a group $G$. How many elements can we add to $S$ to obtain a subgroup $H$ of $G$?

Consider this variant of the question: suppose we have a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$. How many elements can we subtract from $H$ to obtain a subset $S$ of $G$?

They're basically the same question, but the second version shows that the answer is essentially arbitrary. One can start with a subgroup $H$, delete *any* elements to obtain a subset $S$, and then ask the original question about $S$—the answer will (not always but almost always) be that we need to re-include the deleted elements of $H$.

One can easily construct examples in this way where the sizes of $S$, $G$, and $H$ are more or less arbitrary. In particular, the original assumption that $\#S$ divides $\#G$ doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Hmm true, I am still interested if there are special cases which can be arrived by strengthening hypotheses